# Display character started with $st and no more than $max

Tags: php, string

Let I've a string `$str`. How to display a sub-string which is starting from the `$st` symbols after beginning  of `$str` and no more than $max symbols?

Comment: Have a look at [`substr`](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Use of [**substr**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, -1); // returns "de"
```